# [UWP]DeviceInformation FindAllAsync BluetoothLEDevice Incorrect parameter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am developing a Windows Phone application, which is working with BLE devices. In Windows Phone 8.1 it works great, but after that when i updated my phone to Windows 10,the app throws "Incorrect parameter" error. My device is Nokia Lumia 630 with OS build: 10.0.10586.36

```
await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelector())
```

This is the program line, which throws the error.

Can someone help me, how can i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have you figured out a work around?